# Making an image carousel using an Image Slider

Tags: java, android

I am making an image carousel using [Android Image Slider](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider) with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and I'm trying to test if I can implement ArrayList when adding URLs to the adapter but when I add the URLs to the ArrayList, the other data doesn't show, only the last on the Array. It seems that I can't store the URLs to the SliderItem's value. Why is the other image not displaying on the Slider?

I used the default adapter of [Android Image Slider](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider): [SliderAdapterExample.java](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/smarteist/imageslider/SliderAdapterExample.java).

Home.java

```
SliderItem sliderItem = new SliderItem();

    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/xdswuBCXXazoCcJ9t9c0y1DqcEU8Ixog4B6Q2MJaE3Iy84VV7g8GOS8C5b9JgTlFRGg23q_Rjw61Tr68A0mJ9ZnoqJdxPLLvCCZteQBOcaW61KEOQA");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/6-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0542-9ea75fa49452780.jpg");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/7-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0514-261aafdf24310c00.jpg");

    for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++){
        sliderItem.setDescription("Slider Item Added Manually");
        sliderItem.setImageUrl(urls.get(i));
    }

    adapter.addItem(sliderItem);
```

SliderItem.java

```
public class SliderItem {
private String description;
private String imageUrl;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}}
```

Here is what I got for now. Only the last link works. See image below:

[image: Carousel]

https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/7-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0514-261aafdf24310c00.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `adapter.addItem(sliderItem);` within `for` loop.

```
    SliderItem sliderItem = new SliderItem();

    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/xdswuBCXXazoCcJ9t9c0y1DqcEU8Ixog4B6Q2MJaE3Iy84VV7g8GOS8C5b9JgTlFRGg23q_Rjw61Tr68A0mJ9ZnoqJdxPLLvCCZteQBOcaW61KEOQA");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/6-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0542-9ea75fa49452780.jpg");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/7-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0514-261aafdf24310c00.jpg");

    for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++){
        sliderItem.setDescription("Slider Item Added Manually");
        sliderItem.setImageUrl(urls.get(i));

        // here
        adapter.addItem(sliderItem);
    }
```

or

```
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/xdswuBCXXazoCcJ9t9c0y1DqcEU8Ixog4B6Q2MJaE3Iy84VV7g8GOS8C5b9JgTlFRGg23q_Rjw61Tr68A0mJ9ZnoqJdxPLLvCCZteQBOcaW61KEOQA");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/6-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0542-9ea75fa49452780.jpg");
    urls.add("https://www.luxuryproperty.com/uploads/images/7-bedroom-villa-for-sale-dubai_hills_mansions-LP0514-261aafdf24310c00.jpg");

    for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++){
        SliderItem sliderItem = new SliderItem();
        sliderItem.setDescription("Slider Item Added Manually");
        sliderItem.setImageUrl(urls.get(i));

        // here
        adapter.addItem(sliderItem);
    }
```

According to your code, you have three url, so you need three `SliderItem`.But if you put `adapter.addItem(sliderItem);` outside `for` loop, you can get last `SliderItem` only.

Additionally, everytime you add an item to adapter, you need to set `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to `addItem()`.

If my solution has any problem, please let me free to know.

Comment: Oh the second one fixes my problem, stuck for an hour with SliderItem sliderItem = new SliderItem(); outside the for loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: @b0on You're welcome. If the answer is right, please tick for the right answer.